# How to capture loop code output

Tags: c, ruby, linux

here is my loop code

```
#exe2.rb
loop do
  print "#{::Time.now}\r"
  sleep 1
end
```

and I use following c to capture its out:

```
fp = popen("ruby /home/roroco/Dropbox/rbs/ro_cmds/exe2.rb", "r");
while (fgets(var, sizeof(var), fp) != NULL) {
    printf("%s", var);
}
```

but it stuck in `fgets`, how to make it work?

Comment: Is `var` an array or a pointer?

Comment: what do you mean by stuck? Throws some kind of exception or just not proceeding into the loop?

Comment: Ruby buffers the output. Put `$stdout.sync = true` before your loop or call `$stdout.flush` after `print`

Comment: Try changing your ruby code:  change the backslash "r" to backslash "n"

Comment: Why is this tagged `C++`?

Answer (score 3):

This is an effect of buffering. In UNIX `stdout` is line-buffered by default, which means that the `stdio` facility accumulates bytes till some buffer fills or it encounters a `'\n'`. This is beneficial to limit I/O thus improving performance (I/O is slow).

For this reason, change your ruby code to print a new line `'\n'` at the end instead of a carriage return `'\r'` (because [`fgets(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html) is for lines). You don't need to change the C code as `fgets(3)` doesn't chomp the newline.

The Ruby interpreter treats `stdout` the same, unless it's a pipe. If that's the case it's fully buffered. The easiest way to get around that is doing a `STDOUT.flush` after every write in the ruby script.

Comment: If you'd change the Ruby code to issue a new-line, there is not need to add to it C print statement any more as `fgets()` reads the new-line provided by the ruby code.